# Инициализация объекта перечислимого типа

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt5

В коде на С++ натолкнулся на такую инициализацию:

```
Specification = (BulkCode)-1;
```

где

```
BulkCode Specification;

enum BulkCode {
SETFILTER,
SETTRIGGERANDSAMPLERATE,
FORCETRIGGER}
```

Насколько правомерно так писать?

Comment: Правомерно, поскольку элементы традиционного перечисления есть всего лишь именованные константы некоего интегрального типа. Другое дело, что такой стиль является моветоном.

Answer (score 8):

#### В С - разрешено.

Переменные типа `enum BulkCode` имеют то же внутреннее представление, что и один из встроенных целочисленных типов, в который влезают все значения перечисленных констант (на выбор компилятора, `char` или `signed`/`unsigned` `char/short/int/long/long long`).

Тип `enum BulkCode` считается *integer type* и приведение к нему работает по тем же правилам, что и ко встроенным целочисленным типам. Так что, независимо от того, какое представление выбрал компилятор, `(enum BulkCode)-1` будет работать.

[Пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum) раз. [Пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast) два. [Пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integerconversions) три.

---

#### В С++ - нельзя, неопределенное поведение. (Конкретно для этого enum'а.)

<sup>До С++17 результат был unspecified.</sup>
**Если была бы хотя бы одна отрицательная константа, либо если underlying type был бы указан явно как знаковый целый, то было бы разрешено.**

**<sup>В отдельных других случаях, в зависимости от конкретных значений констант в enum'е, это может оказаться разрешено, но полагаться на это не следует, потому что правила слишком запутанные. (Читай ниже.)</sup>**

В С++, если у enum'а underlying type не указан явно<sup>**1**</sup>, то компилятор опять же выбирает его на свое усмотрение<sup>**2**</sup>.

Однако, допустимые значения enum'а не обязательно совпадают с допустимыми значениеми его underlying type.

Диапазон допустимых значений enum'а определяется так:

- Если в enum'е нет отрицательных констант, то диапазон - от `0` до `2^n - 1` (с наименьшим возможным положительным `n`, при котором все константы влезают в диапазон).
- Если отрицательные константы есть, то диапазон - от `-2^(n-1)` до `2^(n-1) - 1` (опять же, с наименьшим возможным `n`, при котором все константы влезают в диапазон).

  <sup>(На системах с one's complement и sign-magnitude представлениями целых нижняя граница для второго случая на 1 выше, но в реальности таких систем по сути нет.)</sup>

В `enum BulkCode {SETFILTER, SETTRIGGERANDSAMPLERATE, FORCETRIGGER};` нет отрицательных констант, так что его диапазон - от `0` до `3` (`n=2`, без знака). А underlying type - любой целый тип не больше `int`.

Когда к enum'у приводится целое число, оно сначала приводится к его underlying type. Если получившийся результат не влезает в допустимый диапазон, то получаем неопределенное поведение. (До С++17 результат был unspecified.)

Для того enum'а, что в вопросе, нет такого underlying type, преобразование `-1` к которому дало бы `3`, так что гарантированно получаем неопределенное поведение.

Будь у нас хотя бы одна отрицательная константа, то `-1` влезал бы в допустимый диапазон, и проблем бы не было.

Однако, даже без отрицательных констант, если бы у констант были такие значения, что допустимый диапазон совпадал бы с диапазоном значений underlying type (например, хотя бы одна константа со значением больше `INT_MAX`, но не больше `UINT_MAX`), то преобразование `-1` к underlying type гарантированно давало бы верхнюю границу допустимого диапазона, и неопределенного поведения бы не было. Условия очень специфичные, поэтому на это лучше не рассчитывать.

[Пруф](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) раз. [Пруф](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8) два.

---

<sup>**1** - Пример явного указания: `enum E : int {a,b};`.</sup>

<sup>**2** - Типы больше `int` ему разрешено брать только если константы не влезают ни в `int`, ни в `unsigned int`.</sup>

Comment: Достаточно всего лишь включить в перечисление дополнительную константу вроде `INVALIDVAL=-1`, и все сразу станет по феншую, и без всяких сомнительных кастов.